# replace a value in object

Tags: php, magento, replace

i have `$result` variable in my magento code that comes from

```
$seller = Mage::getModel('marketplace/seller');
$result=$seller->load($id, 'user_id');
```

and `var_dump($result)` return:

```
    object(Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Seller)#93 (15) {  
 ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract"  
 ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" 
 ["_resourceName":protected]=>  
 string(18) "marketplace/seller" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL  
 ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(29)  
 "marketplace/seller_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false)  
 ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true)  
 ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>NULL   
 ["_data":protected]=> array(13) { ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "15"  
 ["shop_name"]=>   string(3) "aaa" ["shop_description"]=> string(3) "aaa"  
 ["url_path"]=> string(3)    "aaa" ["telephone"]=> string(6) "123456" 

 ["image"]=> NULL  

   ["country"]=>   
 string(2) "IR" ["postcode"]=> string(5)  
 "12441" ["admin_total_earn"]=> NULL    
 ["admin_commission_by_percentage"]=> NULL ["total_vendor_earn"]=> string(4)  
 "0.00" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["created_date"]=> string(19) "2017-06-24  
 15:50:57" } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false)  
 ["_origData":protected]=> array(13) { ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "15"  
 ["shop_name"]=> string(3) "aaa" ["shop_description"]=> string(3) "aaa"  
 ["url_path"]=> string(3) "aaa" ["telephone"]=> string(6) "123456"["image"]=>  
 NULL ["country"]=> string(2) "IR" ["postcode"]=> string(5) "12441"  
 ["admin_total_earn"]=> NULL   
 ["admin_commission_by_percentage"]=> NULL  
 ["total_vendor_earn"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "16"  
 ["created_date"]=> string(19) "2017-06-24 15:50:57" }   
 ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false)  
 ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>  
 array(0) { } }
```

how to replace variable of   ["image"]=NULL   whith '12.jpg'?
like:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                if ($value='image') {
                    $key['image']='12.jpg';
                }
            }
```

Comment: not working @B. Desai

Comment: Aren't those values retrieved from your database? You should set the image there. Otherwise, I'm sure you can set `$result->image = '12.jpg';`